# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' only with Flask

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from scrap import Scrap, Scrap_web3, Scrap_remoteok

app = Flask("Job Scrapper")

db = {}


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/search")
def search():
    keyword = request.args.get("keyword")
    if keyword is None:
        return redirect("/")

    if keyword in db:
        jobs = db[keyword]
    else:
        all_jobs = []

        berlin_script = Scrap(keyword)
        berlin_script.find_job()
        all_jobs.extend(berlin_script.results)

        web3_script = Scrap_web3(keyword)
        web3_script.find_job()
        all_jobs.extend(web3_script.results)

        remoteok_script = Scrap_remoteok(keyword)
        remoteok_script.find_job()
        all_jobs.extend(remoteok_script.results)

        db[keyword] = all_jobs
        jobs = all_jobs

    return render_template("search.html", keyword=keyword, jobs=jobs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**scrap.py**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scrap:
    def __init__(self, keyword):
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.url_list = [
            f"https://berlinstartupjobs.com/skill-areas/{self.keyword}",
            f"https://web3.career/{self.keyword}-jobs",
            f"https://weworkremotely.com/remote-jobs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term={self.keyword}",
        ]
        self.results = []
        self.headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
        }

    def find_job(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url_list[0], headers=self.headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        jobs = soup.find("ul", class_="jobs-list-items").find_all("li")
        for job in jobs:
            title = job.find("h4", class_="bjs-jlid__h").text
            company = job.find("a", class_="bjs-jlid__b").text
            link = job.find("h4", class_="bjs-jlid__h").find("a")["href"]
            job_db = {
                "Title": title,
                "Company": company,
                "URL": link,
            }
        self.results.append(job_db)


class Scrap_web3(Scrap):
    def __init__(self, keyword):
        super().__init__(keyword)

    def find_job(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url_list[1], headers=self.headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        jobs = soup.find("tbody", class_="tbody").find_all("tr")
        for index, job in enumerate(jobs):
            if index == 4:
                continue
            title = job.find(
                "h2", class_="fs-6 fs-md-5 fw-bold my-primary").text
            company = job.find(
                "td", class_="job-location-mobile").find("h3").text
            link = f'https: // web3.career{job.find("td", class_="job-location-mobile").find("a")["href"]}'
            job_db = {
                "Title": title,
                "Company": company,
                "URL": link,
            }
        self.results.append(job_db)


class Scrap_remoteok(Scrap):
    def __init__(self, keyword):
        super().__init__(keyword)

    def find_job(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url_list[2], headers=self.headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        jobs = soup.find_all("li", class_="feature")
        for job in jobs:
            title = job.find("span", class_="title").text
            company = job.find("span", class_="company").text
            link = f"https://weworkremotely.com{job.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and 'remote-jobs' in tag.get('href', ''))['href']}"
            job_db = {
                "Title": title,
                "Company": company,
                "URL": link,
            }
        self.results.append(job_db)
```

`I have no idea why this code has this problem when I try to launch with Flask.
I already checked bs4 could access with those pages and when I printed each one on scrap.py
everything was ok.

When I run this code individually, there are no issues at all, but when I run it as a web application using Flask, the same error keeps occurring. I simply cannot understand why.

If there were a problem with bs4 or the code itself, then running the .py file should also result in an error, but it seems like there is no issue at all.
`

I tried to lauch the code each one scrap.py (no problem)
Checked HTML (no problem)

Answer (score 0):

The `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'` error means that in a call `obj.find_all(...)`, *obj* is *None*. These *obj* values in your code are results of a `soup.find(...)` call, which returns None if there is no such DOM element (HTML tag) in the document.

Ways to fix it:

- Instead of `response.content` downloaded from the web, pass a HTML document as a hard-coded constant string. Then the behavior will be deterministic, no matter where you run the program.
- Modify your Python code so that `soup.find(...)` is able to find a matching DOM element, when used on web pages you are interested in.
- Add a condition like `if soup.find(...) is None:` to your Python code, and make it do something useful for you if the specified DOM element was not found.

More interesting followup questions (please ask them as separate questions on StackOverflow.com):

- When I download a web page with the same URL from a different computer, why is the result different?
- When I download a web page with the same URL from the same computer again, why is the result different?